# Bash array of strings with space character as executable parameters

Tags: bash

There is this code:

test2.cpp (compiled to test2 executable):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
      std::cout << i << " " << argv[i] << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

test.sh (parameters preparing script):

```
some_array=("text1" "text two" "text tree")

input_variables=""

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#some_array[*]} - 1))); do
   input_variables="$input_variables --parameter=\"${some_array[$i]}\""
   echo $input_variables
done

echo "Running: ./test2$input_variables"
./test2 $input_variables
```

Output:

```
$ sh test.sh
--parameter="text1"
--parameter="text1" --parameter="text two"
--parameter="text1" --parameter="text two" --parameter="text tree"
Running: ./test2 --parameter="text1" --parameter="text two" --parameter="text tree"
0 ./test2
1 --parameter="text1"
2 --parameter="text
3 two"
4 --parameter="text
5 tree"
```

I would like to pass to *test2* executable 3 arguments but 5 arguments are passed and there is a problem with space character between words. I would like also to keep input parameters in array like it is presented in *some_array* so I can add there something whenever I want. How to pass these parameters correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding quotes (or escapes) in a variable's value doesn't do anything useful.  Quotes are parsed *before* variables are replaced, so by the time the quotes get there it's too late for them to do anything (see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more examples).  And BTW using `echo` to print a command is extremely misleading, use `set -x` to have the shell print what it thinks is going on.

The best thing to do, as you said in your final note, is to store the parameters in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
some_array=("text1" "text two" "text tree")

input_variables=()

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#some_array[*]} - 1))); do
   input_variables+=("--parameter=${some_array[$i]}")
   echo "${input_variables[@]}"
done

printf "Running:"
printf " %q" ./test2 "${input_variables[@]}"
./test2 "${input_variables[@]}"
```

BTW, arrays are a bash extension, and not always available in plain shells, so you should  run this with `bash`, not `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Call it in this way:

```
./test2 try\ 1 try\ 2
```

You'll get

```
0 ./test
1 try 1
2 try 2
```

Command line arguments are automaticly separated by spaces, but if you escape them are get as part of string.